# URI parse in Kotlin is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, uri

I am trying to open a link that I get from the server in the web browser. when I manually parse a string everything is fine and works well:

```
paymentApi.httpPost(params).responseString{ request, response, result ->
    when(result){
        is Result.Success -> {
            val data = result.get()
            val url = Uri.parse("http://google.com")
            println(url)

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        is Result.Failure -> {
            println(result.get())
        }
    }
}
```

In this code snippet, I am sending a http post request to a valid url and I get valid response. this response contains a simple url to a payment website. when I don't parse that response via uri and enter a url manually, everything is fine. but when I parse the server's response, here is the error that I keep getting:

```
D/Instrumentation: checkStartActivityResult() : Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat="https://pay.ir/payment/gateway/21559471" }
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: atd.com.ekran, PID: 14542
                  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat="https://pay.ir/payment/gateway/21559471" }
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1968)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1622)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4564)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4522)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4883)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4851)
```

as u can see, the url is completely valid. so there is nothing wrong with the response that the server throws me. what am I doing wrong? 
here are some more information that you might need:

1. I am using Kotlin's fuel library to send my http request
2. this url works fine in my iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. so my string, in itself had double quotes mark and that is why uri parse was not working correctly. All I had to do was removing those annoying marks with :

```
  val dataRemoved =  data.replace("\"","")
```

and now everything works correctly.